# Angularjs remove items from scope that are in another scope

Tags: angularjs, filter, scope, compare, http-get

The following is a mock up of what I have using data from the angular site. The goal is to remove any items in scope2 (newdevices) that already exist in scope1 (devices). I have a working model but do not feel it is the best method.

I have a controller that draws data from two different sources. For simplicity i have made the first scope static, whereas the second will take data via httpget from the angular site and this is initiated from a button click. (My prod code needs to use a button so i can inject variables into the call)

```
app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope, $http) {

//Example static data for scope 1
$scope.devices = [
   {"Name":"Around the Horn","City":"London","Country":"UK"},
   {"Name":"B's Beverages","City":"London","Country":"UK"},
   {"Name":"Chop-suey Chinese","City":"Bern","Country":"Switzerland"}
];

//scope 2 data from angular example site that is initiated from a button
$scope.loaddata = function() {
  $http.get("http://www.w3schools.com/angular/customers_mysql.php")
    .then(function (response) {
        $scope.newdevices = response.data.records;
      });
  }
});
```

I then have a filter that compares the scopes:

```
app.filter('matcher', function() {
  return function(newdevices, devices) {
    var array2Ids = []
    angular.forEach(devices, function(value, index) {
      array2Ids.push(value.Name);
    })
  return newdevices.filter(function(val) {
    return array2Ids.indexOf(val.Name) === -1;
  })
 }
});
```

Lastly, I apply the filter to my ng-repeat call:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="customersCtrl">
<button ng-click="loaddata()">load me</button>
  <table>
    <tr ng-repeat="x in newdevices | matcher: devices">
      <td width="300px">{{ x.Name }}</td>
      <td width="150px">{{ x.City }}</td>
      <td width="100px">{{ x.Country }}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

As mentioned, this currently works, but as I am already calling the second scope httpget from a function, is there a way I can integrate the filter into the loaddata function, so it happens all at once and can eliminate the need to filter on the ng-repeat stage?

I am still relatively new to this and have not yet been able to accomplish it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you don't need an angular "filter". Just filter the response data before it gets assigned to $scope.newdevices. below code has been tested, but you get the idea.

```
$scope.loaddata = function() {
$http.get("http://www.w3schools.com/angular/customers_mysql.php")
.then(function (response) {
      //do things here, i.e.
       var array2Ids = [];
       angular.forEach(devices, function(value, index) {
         array2Ids.push(value.Name);
       });
       $scope.newdevices = response.data.records.filter(function(val) {
           return array2Ids.indexOf(val.Name) === -1;
       });
    });
}
```

Comment: This worked great thanks. Just needed to prefix devices with $scope and it worked right away. "angular.forEach($scope.devices,.." One thing I have now discovered is that as I can moving items from newdevices to devices, devices still cahces the old scope data, and will not reflect untill I refresh the page to force a new HTTPget on devices. Is there a way to force reload a scope?

Comment: almost every change made to the scope values should automatically be reflected on the page, that's what 2-way binding is supposed to be. But if the change was made outside of angular, then angular won't be able to detect it. Can you show me how you moved the items and what you mean by devices still caches the old scope data?

Answer (score 0):

Controllers and services can retrieve filters using the `$filter` service.

```
var matcherFn = $filter('matcher');

var result = marcherFn(newdevices, devices);
```

AngularJS filters can be used both in templates and JavaScript.

The example in the Docs:

```
angular.module('filterExample', [])
.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $filter) {
  $scope.originalText = 'hello';
  $scope.filteredText = $filter('uppercase')($scope.originalText);
});
```

For more information, see [AngularJS $filter Service API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$filter).

Comment: Thanks, I will read up on this as can see multiple purposes for it now.